# Float Layout adding custom sized widgets with Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am new to python and kivy, I am trying to learn by making making a small widget:

Main.py File:

```
class start(App):
    def build(self):
        return Holder()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start().run()
```

Code:

```
class Holder(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.size=(300,300)
        super(Holder,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        c=Cell()
        c.pos=(100,100)
        self.add_widget(c)
        print(str(c.pos))

        d=Cell()
        d.pos=(100,0)
        self.add_widget(d)
        print(str(d.pos))

class Cell(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Cell,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0)
            Rectangle(size=(50, 50))

        self.height=50
        self.width=50
```

The issue is, althogh I am adding 2 Cells with different pos, I am still getting them over lapped and both of them are displayed at corner only.

[image]
Could you please make my learn where I went wrong.

EDIT:
I have updated the code for Cell as follows:

```
class Cell(Widget):
    rect=Rectangle(size=(50, 50))
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Cell,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.canvas.add(Color(1, 0, 0))
        self.canvas.add(self.rect)
        self.bind(pos=self.callback_pos)

    def callback_pos(self, value):
        self.rect.pos=self.pos
```

However, now I am receiving the error as "TypeError: callback_pos() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drawing code is

```
with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0)
            Rectangle(size=(50, 50))
```

...and this is exactly what you see, both rectangles have size (50, 50) and are in the default position of (0, 0) because you didn't set that.

If you want the rectangle to appear with the size and shape of your widget, you must bind that yourself - that is, keep a reference to the rectangle and use the widget `bind` method to call a function that updates its position whenever the widget position changes.

This is a little verbose, which is one reason we reccommend using kv language - it does this for you!

```
<Cell>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 0, 0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: 50, 50
```

This will automatically update the pos to match self.pos whenever that changes.

Have you done the kivy pong tutorial? I reccommend doing so. You might also be interested in my [video tutorials](http://inclem.net/pages/kivy-crash-course/).

Edit: In reply to your own edit:

```
rect=Rectangle(size=(50, 50))
```

You should put this line in `__init__`, the way you have it will pass the same rectangle to every instance since it's a class level variable. That *might* actually not crash and work here, but it isn't what you mean and is probably bad practice for that reason.

> However, now I am receiving the error as "TypeError: callback_pos() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

You have the arguments `self, value`. The binding (and all kivy property bindings) actually call with `self, instance, value`. Simply add this extra argument (or catch them all with `*args`).

Comment: I have updated the code, but it is still coming the same, I did not use the KV lang here, I did it code only, and add the new code to question, could you please correct me.

Comment: saw your  site, having not only videos, but along with articles would be great